# Data security under WebGIS by QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-service, qgis2web, security, publishing

We would like to offer our Client a webGIS solution for showing/Monitoring their data. Based on my Knowledge WebGIS by ESRI would be helpful and provide the user with the Login Information and it is safe. However, due to the costs of server, it is not possible for us.

I first offered them ArcGIS Earth. It worked for a while but it is very slow and most importantly it is not possible to Show a feature with classification in Colors and that is what the Client wants.

I lerned a bit About WebGIS through QGIS and did a sample data with it is not clear for me how secure it is as there is no Password defining possibilty and I am not sure where the data is published. Is it under Cloud?

How can I secure this Approach?

Comment: Security is a range. What exactly do you need to protect and how?

Comment: Well for us it important that the data of the Client is safe and not everybody has Access to that. As we donot define any Password when we create webGIS through QGIS, I am wondering if everyone has Access to that data

Comment: how do you create your webGIS from QGis?

Comment: using qgis2Web application----> create web map

Comment: And where do you host that?

Comment: Since you already have a sample with (presumably) shareable sample data, why  not share the sample web map here?

Answer (score 1):

If you created a webmap using qgis2web then the resulting data was most likely saved to your local hard drive or on a server somewhere on your local network.  If the data is on your computer then anyone with access to your computer will be able to see it.  If the data is on a server then anyone with access to the network or server will be able to view the data.  If you plan to put the resulting webmap from qgis2web on a website then the data would be protected by a username and password type system.

If you are asking about how to setup the username and password system then that question is too broad of a topic?

FWIW, I have a few clients using ArcGIS Online and I think the costs are inexpensive.  It really depends on how many users you have.